# Enabling VT-X/AMD-V in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I have only console access. I need VM in my machine.

I have installed virtualbox using sudo apt-get install virtualbox. Since I don't have desktop access, I am not able to access bios settings. I found that virtualization is not enabled.

I installed vnc4server after that vnc shows only console. I understood that I have to install desktop.

Is there any possibility to do that? I can reboot the system. How to access those settings from terminal?

OR

Is there any virtual box which will automatically enable virtualization during installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You should ask someone with an access to physical device to enable this.

Or you can use something like Qemu with software virtualization which may be slow depending on the power of your system.

Comment: Thanks. Does Installing desktop and accessing through vnc help?

Comment: No. The desktop loads after your operating system is up. Bios settings can only be changed before it passes the system to any OS or bootloder.